# Is it possible to have nested dictionary using setdefault, appending to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, setdefault

I would like to have a nested dictionary with a list of values that are attached to the sub-key. Can't get the sub-key to recognise.

```py
month = {}
    for row in date:
        month.setdefault(row[1],{row[0]: []})
        month[row[0]].append(row[4])

print(month[main_key][sub_key])
```

I expect a list of values to be populated out through the appending method. However, I keep getting a keyError.

The desired output:

```
{'row[1]': {'row[0]' :[row[4], row[4], row[4]],
            'row[0]' :[row[4], row[4], row[4]]}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple example of what I think you are trying to achieve:

```
>>> rows = [[1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,3,3], [1,3,5], [2,3,9], [2,3,5]]
>>> ret = {}
>>> for row in rows:
...     ret.setdefault(row[0], {}).setdefault(row[1], []).append(row[2])
...
>>> ret
{1: {2: [3, 4], 3: [3, 5]}, 2: {3: [9, 5]}}
```

How does it work? For each `row`:

1. We look for `row[0]` in `ret` keys. If it is not present, we add the pair `(row[0], {})` to the dict, `{}` being the nested dict. It it is present, we continue.
2. The value `row[1]` is the key of the nested dict. We look for it in `ret[row[0]]` (the first `setdefault` return): if it is not present, we add an empty list.
3. We add the value `row[2]` to the list `ret[row[0]][row[1]]`

Remember that:

```
ret.setdefault(row[0], value_if_absent).func()
```

Means:

```
if row[0] not in ret:
    ret[row[0]] = value_if_absent

ret[row[0]].func()
```

Usaully, `value_if_absent` is a container and `func` is one of `append`, `extend`, `update`, ... methods. But `func` may also be a `setdefault` to create a new container if needed.

Comment: Thanks bud! I got it already but someone deleted my answer. ): Got to get used to the rules in here. Nonetheless, thank you so much, I get a clearer picture with all your explanation.

Comment: @Susan Glad to help! BTW, answering your own question is not forbidden. I don't know why your answer was deleted. Check [the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Let's follow the statements in the block of the for-loop.

The first is:

```
month.setdefault(row[1], {row[0]: []})
```

This will set a value of `{row[0]: []}` (**dictionary**) for the key `row[1]` where the key hasn't been inserted in `month`.

The next statement is:

```
month[row[0]].append(row[4])
```

It appends `row[4]` to a list retrieved from `month` with the key `row[0]`.
This line should error given that even when the key exists in `month`, the value it is paired with is a **dictionary** and not a list.

That line should be written as:

```
month[row[1]][row[0]].append(row[4])
```

`month[row[1]]` retrieves the **dictionary** paired with key `row[1]` which is then indexed to access the list paired with `row[0]`.

Comment: I kind of get it, it still gives me the same error. I want to set fixed keys so doing setdefault for both keys works. Nonetheless, thank you so much!

Comment: I should have stated my desire output clearly, my bad.